# How to avoid browser from rendering malacious content after the response is dispatched

Tags: apache, security, http, https

We are currently working on OWASP security fixes & we identified one attack scenario for which we are trying to figure out a possible solution:

1. User hits a valid HTTPRequest to our application. The URL in user's browser is set to our application url e.g. http(s)://www.abc.com/request
2. Application processes the request and dispatches the response through Apache.
3. While the response is en-route, an attacker intercepts the response and replaces the content of entire response with some malicious site or message like 'You Are Hacked!!'
4. The response gets rendered in user's browser, with the URL still pointing to http(s)://www.abc.com/request in the browser but the content being malicious. This makes the user believe that it is still in our application.

We could replicate this scenario through our proxy tool. Is there any way to identify & prevent rendering such responses in the browser through Apache or custom HTTP headers?

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated.

### added after first answer:

Consider one more scenario:

1. User hits a valid HTTPRequest to our application.
2. Attacker intercepts the request & forwards it to some malicious site instead of our application. Here too, the URL in user's browser is set to application URL e.g. http(s)://www.abc.com/request but the content will be that of malicious site.

This could also be possible with HTTPS.

In scenario (2), while our website is HTTPS, the malicious website is plain HTTP. Hence, the certificate warning doesn't occur on the browser when the request is routed.

Comment: If the attacker can completely replace everything in the response from your server, your server can't do anything to prevent this. I.e. they'd just as easily delete any extra information you've added to the response such as a custom header. If you want to prevent casual MITM attacks, switch to HTTPS only.

Comment: For the HTTPS variant, they have to be able to present a forged certificate that the client's machine will accept as valid for your domain. This either means they've already compromised the clients machine (so, far simpler attacks are possible without going to this effort) or they've compromised a CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTTP, there is not much you can do about this, because the interceptor could also modify any HTTP headers, not just the content. If the authenticity of the responses of your application is important, do not serve via HTTP at all and educate your users in the usage and verification of HTTPS websites.

With HTTPS, the attacker should not be able to replace content of the response without the user's browser noticing and aborting, so step 3 of the first scenario should be impossible. 'Should', because this assumes the safety of HTTPS and the underlying cryptography, and that the attacker can't get hold of a technically valid certificate for the attacked domain.

### Edit:

Step 2 of your second scenario should also be impossible with HTTPS, under the limits of the assumptions above. (HTTPS being save, implemented safely and the attacker not holding a certificate for the attacked domain.) If your proxy *was* able to perform this attack (or the one from the first scenario) **on a HTTPS connection**, please

- make sure the proxy did so without access to your service's certificate private key
- make sure that the url presented to the client was indeed from your service's domain
- if both so, follow responsible disclosure in informing the maintainer of the affected software (probably the client software, as in the second scenario, the request might not even reach the real service)

Comment: @user36009 When requesting a HTTPS URL and being redirected to a HTTP one, browsers and other clients should definitely abort or issue a very noticeable warning.